# How to place code when writing file in a loop in java

Tags: java, file, io

I have a code that looks like this:

```
while (/*condition*/) {
   //...
   if (/*condition*/) {
       //...
   } 
   else if (/*condition*/) {
       //...
   }
   //...
}
```

I want to write file in the if and else if statements. Where should I put the try-catch-finally blocks to open the stream to write file? Should I put the whole loop in the try block? Like this:

```
try {
    //open stream
    while (/*condition*/) {
       //...
       if (/*condition*/) {
           //...
           //write file
       } 
       else if (/*condition*/){
           //...
           //write file
       }
       //...
    }
}
catch(IOException e) {
    //...
}
finally {
    //...
}
```

Is it the right way to do this?

Comment: StackOverflow is for "making it work", you might want to try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (after you come up with a solution attempt).

Comment: @C-Otto A working solution, not just an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely shall wrap both of the statements in their own try-catch blocks, first of all, wrapping the entire execution in a single try-catch is 99% of the time a bad practice.

What's more, it will allow you to easier work around the error because you will know either it's being thrown inside the if or inside the else if.

```
try{ instantiate writer etc...
}
catch(...){...}
while(){
   some code here 
   if(){
       try{
       some code here
       write file here
       }
       catch (IOException e){
       // Error happened in the if...
       }
   } 
   else if(){
       try{...
       }
   }
}
```

Using it like this will still allow you to code a behavior that happens after both catches (like the finally in the code you wrote) by just writing code outside the if and the else-if.